# c3p0 setIdleConnectionTestPeriod units

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

This is a very simple question but the documentation has not made it clear to me what units this function accepts.  I assume seconds but am trying to confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [c3p0 connection pooling configuration page](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration) contains a great deal of detail on the available options. The default unit of measure for the `idleConnectionTestPeriod` property is in seconds.

Comment: Thanks.  Bookmarking this page, the javadoc that come up on google searches are far less useful

Comment: its a bummer they don't javadoc the info